SonarQube is failing to start due to an issue with Elasticsearch not being able to load the necessary native library
[enter image description here][1]I am using sonarqube-10.7.0.96327 version. it was working fine till. but today tried to start sonar service so it is giving below error.
My java version is - java 17.0.12 2024-07-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.12+8-LTS-286)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.12+8-LTS-286, mixed mode, sharing)[enter image description here][2]
i tried checking logs ES as well as SQ, so followed and added zstd-v1.5.6-win64 to the ES/lib ...but still not luck.
PS D:\docs\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\bin\windows-x86-64> .\StartSonar.bat
Starting SonarQube...
2024.10.25 11:34:49 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory D:\docs\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\temp
2024.10.25 11:34:49 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:52449]
2024.10.25 11:34:49 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [D:\docs\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java -Xms4m -Xmx64m -XX:+UseSerialGC -Dcli.name=server -Dcli.script=./bin/elasticsearch -Dcli.libs=lib/tools/server-cli -Des.path.home=D:\docs\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=D:\docs\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\temp\conf\es -Des.distribution.type=tar -cp D:\docs\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\elasticsearch\lib*;D:\docs\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\elasticsearch\lib\cli-launcher* org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher
2024.10.25 11:34:49 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2024.10.25 11:34:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2024.10.25 11:34:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[WEB_SERVER] from [D:\docs\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\docs\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\temp -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1] -cp ./lib/sonar-application-10.7.0.96327.jar;D:\docs\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-2.2.224.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer D:\docs\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\temp\sq-process8445048974899513524properties
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.sonar.process.PluginSecurityManager (file:/D:/docs/sonarqube-10.7.0.96327/sonarqube-10.7.0.96327/lib/sonar-application-10.7.0.96327.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.sonar.process.PluginSecurityManager
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally - check the logs at D:\docs\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\logs\sonarqube.log
ERROR: Elasticsearch died while starting up, with exit code 1
2024.10.25 11:35:02 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]: 1
2024.10.25 11:35:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped
2024.10.25 11:35:16 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[Web Server] is stopped
2024.10.25 11:35:16 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
PS D:\docs\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\sonarqube-10.7.0.96327\bin\windows-x86-64>
